# Determining minimum number of edges to remove in a bipartite graph so the maximum path length is 2

Tags: graphs, np-hard

I stumbled upon the following problem during my research.

I have a bipartite graph, and I want to determine the minimum number of edges to to remove so that the maximum path length in the resulting graph is 2.

Is this problem NP-hard? I was trying to come up with a polynomial time algorithm (and failed) and also tried to prove its NP-hardness, but also having a hard time.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out this is indeed NP-hard. This is equivalent to finding the maximum spanning star forest in a bipartite graph, which in turn is as hard as finding the minimum dominating set in a bipartite graph, which is NP-hard.

Comment: Did you by any chance created two accounts? If yes please [follow this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Could you elaborate your answer?